# Unable to install Playwright on an Azure Function using Python

Tags: python, azure-functions, github-actions

I am trying to install playwright for python on an Azure function, deploying via github actions.

When I attempt to run, the program fails at the point I attempt to use playwright.  I know, because I haven't managed to successfully install playwright as part of my deployment to the azure function.

I have read [this](https://dev.to/azure/running-headless-chromium-in-azure-functions-with-puppeteer-and-playwright-2fgk) awesome blog from the Microsoft Azure team, which explains how to do this for node.js.  But I can't figure out the right build steps to do this with python.

I have got the following error in my Azure function to confirm the failed installation.
[image: here]

I am using github actions to deploy the change but it's not accepting my "playwright install" command.  I'm not sure why as I'm running in a linux venv and have installed all the right pip modules including playwright.

Here is the image of my github actions deployment, I have temporarily commented out the playwright installation attempt but the code is [image: here]

Finally, I have got the github actions error from previous seen here.  [image: here].

I have tried to adjust where I introduce the venv in my build script.
I have also tried various ways to install the playwright chromium browser on the image.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you add this code in your github action and try to run it again - - name: Install dependencies
        run: pip install -r requirements.txt
      - name: Install Playwright
        run: playwright install

Comment: The installation now works, thank you.  But it's still not quite finding playwright when I run my azure function.

The installation is put into:
Chromium 113.0.5672.53 (playwright build v1060) downloaded to /home/runner/.cache/ms-playwright/chromium-1060

But the Azure function is throwing an exception looking for it here:
Exception occurred when attempting to extract prices: Executable doesn't exist at /home/.cache/ms-playwright/chromium-1060/chrome-linux/chrome

The directories don't quite line up.  Any tips?  Thanks so much again

Answer (score 0):

I tried installing playwright in my Azure Function as dependency in requirements.txt with Github Actions and it was successful, Refer below:-

**My Github action workflow:-**

You can find the complete workflow in this [**Link**](https://rhysd.github.io/actionlint/#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).

Workflow code [**reference**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-how-to-github-actions?tabs=python)

```yaml
name: Azure Function CI/CD

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  build-and-deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: Checkout code
      uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name: Set up Python 3.10
      uses: actions/setup-python@v2
      with:
        python-version: '3.10'

    - name: Create and activate virtual environment
      run: |
        python -m venv .venv
        source .venv/bin/activate

    - name: Install dependencies
      run: pip install -r requirements.txt

    - name: Install Playwright
      run: |
        python -m pip install playwright
        playwright install

    - name: Deploy to Azure Function
      uses: azure/functions-action@v1
      with:
        app-name: siliconfunc124
        package: .
        publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZURE_FUNCTIONAPP_PUBLISH_PROFILE }}
        slot-name: Production
        python-version: '3.10'
        worker-runtime: python
        app-settings: |
          PLAYWRIGHT_BROWSERS_PATH=/home/site/wwwroot/.local/lib/playwright-browsers
          PLAYWRIGHT_SKIP_BROWSER_DOWNLOAD=1
```

**Output:-**

[image]

I added one additional step with Install Playwright just for validation and it worked as it state requirement already satisfied.

[image]

**Function Deployment was successful like below:-**

[image]

***I tried running the Deployed Function in Azure Portal and it ran successfully, Refer below:-***

[image]

**Monitoring section did not raise any warning**, Refer below:-

[image]

If the error persists, Make sure to add the below settings in your configuration referred from this [**Medium blog**](https://gkushang.medium.com/playwright-failed-to-launch-browsers-how-to-solve-8b01d03fe5b9) which you can refer:-

[image]

[image]

```
PLAYWRIGHT_BROWSERS_PATH /home/site/wwwroot/.local/lib/playwright-browsers
PLAYWRIGHT_SKIP_BROWSER_DOWNLOAD
```

Comment: Whilst this installs chromium locally as part of the github build I don't see it being deployed as part of the azure function deployment.  When I browse the deployed image there's no chromium browser accessible.  In your example I don't see you using playwright chromium in azure functions to validate that its being used?

Also the configuration for PLAYWRIGHT_ etc. isn't valid as part of the build up build action from the warning Warning: Unexpected input(s) 'app-settings'...

Comment: Currently I have done this as a workaround, but it's pretty disgusting:

    - name: Copy Playwright Chromium into deployment 
      shell: bash
      run: |
        mkdir -p .python_packages/cache/ms-playwright/chromium-1060
        cp -r /home/runner/.cache/ms-playwright/chromium-1060/. .python_packages/cache/ms-playwright/chromium-1060
        popd

Comment: An alternative instead of copy task is to use Playwright install path to install the playwright in the Functions path, Refer here-  - name: Install Playwright
      run: |
        python -m pip install playwright
        playwright install --install-path /home/site/wwwroot/.local/lib/playwright-browsers